# Dataflow Flex template while running throwing error for all default parameters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have created a flex template for dataflow and it got build using gcloud successfully but while running the template, it is throwing the error for all default parameters that are supposed to be taken directly from gcloud run command. Below is the error:

- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class interface org.ccm.templates.MongoDbToBigQuery$Options missing a property named 'serviceAccount'.

I am using google provided docker image only i.e. java11.

Command for gcloud build:

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template build gs://hdfc-ergo-artifacts/templates_m/Flex/flextemplate.json \ --image-gcr-path=asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/prj-srv/mongodbtobigquery-flex/dataflow/flextemplate:latest \ --sdk-language=JAVA \ --flex-template-base-image=JAVA11 \
 --metadata-file=src/main/java/org/metadata/mongodb-to-bigquery-image-spec-metadata.json \ --jar=target/dynamic-templates-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar \  --env=FLEX_TEMPLATE_JAVA_MAIN_CLASS=org.templates.MongoDbToBigQuery \  --worker-region=asia-south1 \  --dataflow-kms-key=projects/prj-shared/locations/asia-south1/keyRings \ --service-account-email=service-account-email\ --subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/projects/prj-shared/regions/asia-south1/subnetworks \  --temp-location=gs://fromMongo_Dir1/ --staging-location=gs://MongoDbToBigQuery_Stage/ \ --disable-public-ips
```

Comment: Can you also include the gcloud command you used to create the dataflow?

Comment: Hi @PiyushPatil I have edited the question with the command.

Comment: Can you Confirm that the serviceAccount property is listed in that metadata file?

Comment: No @PiyushPatil, its a default parameter so I have not added it in the metadata file.

Comment: Can you try this? gcloud dataflow flex-template build gs://hdfc-ergo-artifacts/templates_m/Flex/flextemplate.json \
  --image-gcr-path=asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/prj-srv/mongodbtobigquery-flex/dataflow/flextemplate:latest \
  --sdk-language=JAVA \
  --flex-template-base-image=JAVA11 \
  --metadata-file=src/main/java/org/metadata/mongodb-to-bigquery-image-spec-metadata.json \
  --jar=target/dynamic-templates-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
  --env=FLEX_TEMPLATE_JAVA_MAIN_CLASS=org.templates.MongoDbToBigQuery

Comment: Yeah I tried this also, and was getting the same error.

Comment: Able to resolve it after removing the unnecessary dependencies from Pom files.